# In Java, why does char ch disagree with String command?

Tags: java, arrays, switch-statement

When I'm writing codes for my switch statement, I declared this for receiving input along with new class of Array,

```
    ArrayList list = new ArrayList();

    Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);

    printCommands();

    while(s.hasNext())
    {
        String command = s.next();
        char ch = command.charAt(0);
```

but when I'm in the while loop, for case "a" (add integer to array), this line disagreed because `ch` is declared as `char` and eclipse suggested to switch it as string, but it still causes error.

```
switch(command)
        {
            case "c":
                list.clear();
            return;

            case "a":
                ch = s.next(); //s.next() gets the error due to ch?
                list.add(ch);
```

Comment: what error is displayed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A `char` is not a `String`. `scan.next()` returns a `String`. If you want to get new input and use the first character in that new input as `ch`, I suggest using:

```
char ch = scan.next().charAt(0);
```

However, since in your question you are stating that you want to add the integer to the array, i suggest using

```
int intToAdd = scan.nextInt();
```

eg: this should work for you

```
ArrayList list = new ArrayList();

Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);

while (s.hasNext()) {
    String command = s.next();
    char ch = command.charAt(0);
    switch (command) {
        case "c":
            list.clear();
            return;
        case "a":
            ch = s.next().charAt(0); // no more error
            list.add(ch);
            break;
        case "e":
            // this will print all of the array just for testing purposes
            System.out.println(list.toString());
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: This one makes sense the most and it works successfully. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
switch(ch) {
case 'c':
// ...
case 'a':
// ...
```

It's a `char`, not a `String` you're dealing with. Notice the single quotes!

Comment: Sorry. I didn't see yours. Yours is also correct and has practically the same information. Not the down voter. I could, but won't use the down vote as a strategy.

Answer (score 1):

The [Scanner#next()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#next--) method return type is String. That is why you can not assign its result to a char variable. And you already have used that:

```
String command = s.next();
```

You can not use the same method and assign its result to a char.

```
ch = s.next(); //s.next() gets the error due to ch?
```